# My phone turned off while i was recording audio. How do I recover the file?

Tags: data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-6, audio-recording

I recently was recording audio (an interview) by using the native Voice app on my Samsung Galaxy S6. I paused the recording without having the time to save it. My phone turned off automatically and then restarted (it happens sometimes).

When I tried to go back into the app, the file was missing. I searched in the audio files folder, to no avail. I'm under the impression that the file must be somewhere even though it was not saved, because I see that there is a difference between the remaining space on my hdd before and after the recording (which corresponds to approximately 150Mb).

I downloaded several recovery apps off of the Google Store, but I wasn't lucky.

Has anyone experienced something similar and if yes, did you find a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you find a LOST.DIR folder in your internal storage? Corrupted or orphaned files are often stored in that folder..
There's a problem though..  they’re renamed with seemingly random strings of numbers and any file suffixes are stripped. Download a lost.dir file viewer or something and you're good to go..

HOPE IT HELPSSS...